# I want to remove/delete '#' in below statement (in oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to remove/delete '#' in below statement. Please provided SQL query,

`CHK_ID=2001,2002,2003` and `chk_name` respectively.

```
2001    CAR LEASE - LTO REGISTRATION (PLATES ENDING IN #): BOOKS ENTRIES IN SYSTEM FOR PAYMENT        AND REMITTANCE TO BPI
2002    "NUMBERED FORM (EXCLUDE ATM CARDS) - WORKING SUPPLY:
SURPRISE COUNT THE # WORKING SUPPLY NUMBERED FORMS (EXCLUDE ATM CARDS) # TO MATCH WITH THE INVENTORY RECORD AND THE NUMBER FORMS ARE IN SEQUENCE. SUCH SURPRISE CHECK SHOULD MAKE REFERENCE TO DUAL CONTROL RECORD ON RELEASE DATE AND SERIAL #"
2003     PERFORM RECORDS FILE CLEAN OUT # AT LEAST ANNUALLY. THIS CLEAN OUT ALLOWS THE DISPOSAL OF ALL # NON-ESSENTIAL RECORDS NO LONGER NEEDED OR VITAL RECORDS BEYOND THE APPROVED RETENTION PERIOD
```

Comment: Please don't beg people to write queries for you. Instead try it yourself and show your attempts when you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You need [`REPLACE` function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php)

The syntax for the Oracle/PLSQL REPLACE function is:

`REPLACE( string1, string_to_replace, [ replacement_string ] )`

So, in your case it would be `REPLACE(field,'#','')` where `field` is the field your want make changes to.

[Here is **SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/26038)